# Error when Git rebase --quit, --continue, and --abort

Tags: reactjs, git, github, git-rebase

I'm trying to rebase my QA branch to main branch, and it was asking me to resolve the conflicts. There were some issues that I needed to solve first so I did git rebase --abort. then I tried to continue with git rebase --continue but failed with errors. Then I also try git rebase --quit and git rebase --abort but also had errors. Anyone knows what was wrong with it? Thank you in advance!

```
PS C:\Users\Desktop\SDP-React> git rebase --abort
warning: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/head-name': No such file or directory
PS C:\Users\Desktop\SDP-React> git rebase --quit
Deletion of directory '.git/rebase-merge' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) n
error: could not remove '.git/rebase-merge'
PS C:\Users\Desktop\SDP-React> git rebase main
fatal: It seems that there is already a rebase-merge directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
case, please try
        git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
If that is not the case, please
        rm -fr ".git/rebase-merge"
and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something
valuable there.

PS C:\Users\Desktop\SDP-React> git rebase --continue
warning: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/head-name': No such file or directory
PS C:\Users\Desktop\SDP-React> git rebase main
fatal: It seems that there is already a rebase-merge directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
case, please try
        git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
If that is not the case, please
        rm -fr ".git/rebase-merge"
and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something
valuable there.
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is noting in `.git/rebase-merge`, your safe bet is to delete that folder, and `reset --hard` your repository, to go back to a state before the rebase.

Then you can try the rebase again, and resolve conflicts again.

Note: the `.git` folder itself is hidden, so you need to [configure your Windows File Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-97fbc472-c603-9d90-91d0-1166d1d9f4b5) to [display "Hidden items"](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/).

Once the folder is deleted, a new rebase can indeed take place, as the [OP Thi Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16229424/thi-nguyen) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72181902/error-when-git-rebase-quit-continue-and-abort#comment127574387_72182616).

Comment: The thing is deleting '.git/rebase-merge' seems also not an option. It keeps saying deleting failed

```
PS C:\Users\thi.nguyen\Desktop\Thi Nguyen\sdp-final\SDP-React> git rebase --quit
Deletion of directory '.git/rebase-merge' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) y
Deletion of directory '.git/rebase-merge' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) y
Deletion of directory '.git/rebase-merge' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) y
Deletion of directory '.git/rebase-merge' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) y
Deletion of directory '.git/rebase-merge' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) 
```

Comment: @ThiNguyen I mean closing the CMD/Powershell session, and removing the folder from the Windows File Explorer. Then opening an new shell and trying again, after a `git reset --hard` (assuming your `git status` is clean: no work in progress)

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with this process. could you please help me with this? which folder to delete and how to delete it?

Comment: @ThiNguyen Simply delete the folder `.git/rebase-merge` in your repository. Select it in the file explorer, and click on "Delete".

Comment: I don't see that repository anywhere. I think I also see that error when I tried to git rebase --continue

Comment: @ThiNguyen The .git folder is hidden. Make sure your [Windows file explorer shows "hidden items"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-97fbc472-c603-9d90-91d0-1166d1d9f4b5), as [explained here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/).

Comment: @ThiNguyen Great, well done! I have edited the answer to make clear the `.git/` folder is an hidden one.

Comment: that's right. that's the folder hidden. I really appreciate your help. Thanks!